# Can I get the URL of any other browser window?

Tags: java, php, plugins

I want to read the web address of all open windows. As soon as the window closes, I should know it too.

One way to do this is by asking the user to download a firefox plugin. This plugin should monitor the user web address.

But is this possible? How to go about executing it. I am pretty decent in Java and PHP.

EDIT:

What if the user wants to give permission to access all the websites he or she visits?
I want to display in a visual manner the statistics of the sites being visited by users who grant permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, this cannot be done with standard JavaScript/DOM methods that run inside a page, for security and privacy reasons.

You could definitely do it with a Firefox add on, plugin or extension.

I suggest reading the [Firefox addons developer guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Firefox_addons_developer_guide) and the [Developer Hub](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/) in general. The language used to develop for Firefox is JavaScript.

[nsIWindowMediator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWindowMediator) can be used to enumerate open windows, and properties can be obtained through the [nsIDOMWindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIDOMWindow) objects. As explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Firefox_addons_developer_guide/Using_XPCOM%E2%80%94Implementing_advanced_processes#Get_window),

> "While you can use JavaScript to get child windows opened from the parent window, you cannot get dialogs or windows that have no relation to that window. To overcome this limitation, nsIWindowMediator makes it possible to access all of Firefox's windows."

Answer (score 1):

this likely violates the same origin policy, which rules this out
it basically controls the code so that it does not read anything it did not create
so no spying can be done

Answer (score 1):

No, this would be a major security and privacy issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a security violation similar to sniffing; and would require certain privileges to run on each platform (such as an activeX or plugin or a privileged applet).

However, this can be done using javascript **only the page containing the script it self is responsible for opening windows** (meaning not all windows such as window opened by user) - if that is what you are looking for, let me know.